# How to configure/setup memory for OBIEE to run faster

Tags: java, oracle, obiee

I am new to OBIEE. I just install OBIEE 10 by default with

> -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Xmx512m

and it's too slow. How to config it to run faster. Thank you for all help.

Answer (score 2):

Set GO_FASTER=TRUE and RANDOM_SPEED_MULTIPLIER=42.

Jokes aside you can't just expect some parameter to automagically make something "run faster". Especially picking out java params is pretty much grasping for straws.

You're not specifying WHAT is running slow. Are the queries taking ages? Are you running OBI on a 25MHz 386 host with Windows 3.1?

Comment: Thank you for your help and sorry about not clear information. I installed OBI on new environment to linux x86 (from sparc 10) but it seems too slow when I try to view the reports with many users in the same times. I installed it with default settings, I wish it faster than default how can I config somethings? 
p/s: Sorry for my bad English *_*

Comment: Now, in oc4j file I try to set -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Xmx512m to -XX:MaxPermSize=16384m -Xmx16384m. I wish it will faster